# Bootstrap 3 logo between left and right nav (not centered)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, nav

Im trying to add my logo to my bootstrap 3 navigation. My goal is to achieve this:
[MY NAV WITH LOGO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgVY6.png)
It shouldn't be centered and SHOULD be bigger than navigation panel (like in picture). I know that there are many soutions for those problems, but I've tried many of them and effect was poor.
Can anybody help me with this?
If it's necessary I can post any CSS or HTML code.
Thanks.

Edit: I did it, by using proper media queries nad manually positioned logo with margin.

Comment: Code is always helpful. Try to post a jsfiddle or a codepen link.

Comment: Ok.
JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/zv6j3xk2/    (stretch to see desktop version  )
It's not equivalent, but shows the idea of my navigation

Comment: It made me smile when I saw you included bootstrap code inside the fiddle :). You can import css libraries by using `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://boostrap.css"/>`.

Comment: Your problem is still not clear to me. What shouldn't be centered? That red menu icon? Centered how, vertically or horizontally?  Which is the navigation panel in the picture, the black menu?

Comment: I just copy/paste everything :D
"shouldn't be centered" it's about logo. I tried to explain that I have for example 5 menu items on the left side and just two (login, register) on the right side. Logo should be between "right items" and "left items".
In the JSFIDDLE logo should be beetween "menu 3.1" and "menu 5"

Edit: "Left side menu items" are dynamic. Sometimes there are 3 items and sometimes 5